# Setting height of layers without using absolute positioning

Tags: html, css, css-position

https://jsfiddle.net/7ba7sczz/

```
<body>
    <div class="first">
    </div>

    <div class="second">
    </div>
</body>
```

css

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    background: red;
}

.first {
    background: green;   
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px; 
 }

.second {
    background: yellow;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px; 
}
```

How is it possible to keep 100px height of yellow layer, lock it in the bottom of body and give all available space to green layer? So if window has 1000px height, first 900px is green and last 100px is yellow. Can you help to do it without using absolute/relative positioning?

Comment: I'm sure it's 30 pages into obscurity by now.  It's just that it was a fiddle with 3 DIVs, and a question about how they could cooperate. Actually...  Here is the Fiddle.  http://jsfiddle.net/juansg_eng/BCJ6C/119/  The solution was to add a "display: flex" to the middle div.  Hope that helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
.first {
    height: calc(100% - 100px);
    background-color: green;
}
.second {
    height: 100px;
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/keysox/bktLuh2x/

Browser support: http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc

Comment: The only thing you might have to worry about here is with browser support. Some useful information about calc: https://css-tricks.com/a-couple-of-use-cases-for-calc/